# Do TRS-80 Model I and Model III load and execute /CMD files using specific memory addresses?

Tags: file-format, trs-80, trs-80-model-iii

`/CMD` files on the various TRS-80 Model I and III OSes are machine code command files.

They seem to have some internal format but not really a file header.

They often start with `01 02` and then a 16-bit address that looks like where the file should be loaded, and then Z80 code. But one starts with `05 06` followed by a 6-character string, but another starts with `01 02` followed by a sensible address but then followed by a 7-character string. So I can't make out the pattern.

I can't find either the format of these files or the method they are loaded and executed by the machine documented on the internet. I also can't find source code of any of the emulators that support running them directly from the host computer's file system.

Does somebody know how these /CMD commands work?

Comment: Quick googling for "load module", which is apparently the name for /CMD files gave http://electrickery.xs4all.nl/comp/trs80/doc/Trscmdff.txt

Comment: @ninjalj: You're so much faster at this than me! I just started writing up an answer after I found another copy of the same document here: https://www.tim-mann.org/trs80/doc/ldosq1-4.pdf#page=42

Answer (score 3, accepted):

/CMD files are a series of tagged records. Some record types have meaning only for certain features of some of the TRS-80 DOSes. Only two seem important for loading and executing them.

```
byte:        type
byte:        size* in bytes
bytes[size]: data
```

*`size` 0 → 256 bytes
*`size` for `type 1` only, `size` 1 → 257 bytes, `size` 2 → 258 bytes

```
type 1:     object code (load block)
data[0..1]: load address, 16-bit little-endian
data[2...]: the actual program code & data

type 2:     transfer address (entry address)
data[0..1]: address execution begins, 16-bit little-endian
```

There should be one `type 2` field, it should be the last field, and it indicates the end of the file.

All `type`s up to `0x1F` can be otherwise skipped by using the `size` field.

All `type`s above `0x1F` are invalid. Perhaps the file is not really a /CMD file or is corrupt.

There is often garbage following the `type 2` field. (Perhaps they were written to disk in sizes rounded to the next exact sector size?)

---

I think I might have found it. There's a "hex2cmd" command on Ubuntu:

> **hex2cmd** - convert Intel hex format to TRS-80 CMD format

And it goes on to say

> The LDOS Quarterly, April 1, 1982 (Vol 1,  No  4) 
>   ⟨http://www.tim-mann.org/misosys.html⟩, has documentation of the
>   TRS-80 DOS CMD file format.

While I didn't find it in the link they gave, I did find the LDOS Quarterly they mention. It's in a column called [Roy’s Technical Corner](https://www.tim-mann.org/trs80/doc/ldosq1-4.pdf#page=42).

([ninjalj](https://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/15021/do-trs-80-model-i-and-model-iii-load-and-execute-cmd-files-using-specific-memor#comment49828_15021) found [another copy](http://electrickery.xs4all.nl/comp/trs80/doc/Trscmdff.txt) much faster than than me while I was writing up my answer.)

And now I've found a much more recent post on this topic by the blog of Jim Lawless: [Understanding TRS-80 CMD Files](https://lawlessguy.wordpress.com/2016/12/04/understanding-trs-80-cmd-files/)

The post even includes the C source for Jim's own tool for scanning the CMD files. He also mentions some confusing aspects that the documentation didn't make clear.